# Does Every Shell command in linux calls a system call at the back end

Tags: linux, shell, unix, operating-system, system-calls

I have been asked to find a shell command that doesn't make any system call. I have searched a lot and finally ended up here asking that is there any command in linux shell or unix that doesn't call a system call at the back end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of what a shell is, how does it run the commands.

The shell is an interpreter. Roughly speaking there is a single interpreter loop

```
do {
   get_next_command();
   switch(next_command){
   cmd_alias: ...
   cmd_break: ...
     ...
   }
} while (true);
```

Now think, which command just updates the internal structures of the shell process and which command needs to call the operating system to perform its function.

Comment: Thanks For your input , but can you be more specific about any of the commmand that updates the internal structures.

Comment: You could also `strace`  the shell itself (or each non-builtin command)

Comment: And you could study the source code a shell, either of `bash` or of simpler shells like `sash`

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes and No

*The **Yes** part*...

There are a number of shell built-ins that handle control flow or definitions for the shell's macro processor programming language.

Only a few of the built-ins intrinsically need to make any system calls; in general they just change state inside the shell's memory image.

*The **No** part*...

You actually can't even just type *Enter* at the shell without having a number of system calls run. The shell might wait(2) to see if any children have terminated, it may check the time, it usually prints a prompt ... and of course it reads the next command.